# Headless CMS - inheritance/polymorphism

Tags: graphql, contentful, headless-cms

Does anyone know WHY Contentful (and most other headless CMS products like GraphCMS) do not support inheritance by interface, but the concept of polymorphism at field level by using a union as both seems to be useful and add value for different use cases?

Sometimes it is important to know the type and make sure the object has some fields (interface inheritance) and sometimes it is not important and polymorphism by a union field is useful.

Also any other solution/model design patterns?

So I want to achieve this (at the GraphQL layer):

```
interface ContentItem {
  title: string;
}

type SpecificContentItemA implements ContentItem {
  body: string;
}

type SpecificContentItemB implements ContentItem {
  body: string;
}

type Space {
  items: ContentItem;
}
```

Instead of the current feature of Contentful:

```
type SpecificContentItemA {
  body: string;
}

type SpecificContentItemB {
  body: string;
}

type Space {
  items: SpecificContentItemA | SpecificContentItemB;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way I would do this is by creating three content types:

- ContentItem
- SpecificContentItemA
- SpecificContentItemB

Then I would reference *ContentItem* in both the sub-types to force all fields from *ContentItem* to be in the sub-types.

You can configure the reference in your sub types to show the *ContentItem* as a card. Thus you would see the fields of *ContentItem* when browsing a *SpecificContentItem*, not only the reference.

---

[image]

---

However, there is no way to prevent users from creating a *ContentItem* without referencing it to a sub type. This is not perfect, but Contentful is adding more and more features. Maybe you could ask your question and the community forum.

Comment: Tanks, I think your solution then is composition instead of inheritance as you mean:

`specificContentItemA1 -> ref -> contentItem1
specificContentItemB1 -> ref -> contentItem2`

But wat I was really wondering was why most headless CMS do not support real inheritance as this can be very useful.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would cause technial issues with content.